# How to open modal dialog in active tab. when user click a button on chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to open a dialog in my active tab html instead of google chrome extension html when use click a button on the google chrome extension. Dialog should be open in between of my active tab page.

Do you know how to do that?

Do you have any reference or code sample?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please include if so

Comment: You have to inject your own [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in the page.